# How to disable interrupts for one instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt

Is there any other way to disable interrupts for the duration of **only one instruction** in [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) than using the `CLI` instruction?

Comment: Why would you even need that?

Comment: Also note `CLI` doesn't affect software interrupts.

Comment: I require this in a question of my assignment

Comment: So here's another question:  why would you use an alternative to CLI, SEI?

Comment: @IraBaxter For example, if you are in protected mode and cannot disable interrupts because you aren't the kernel.

Comment: You asked *2* questions:   is there something to disable interrupts other than CLI,  and is there something that does it for only *one* instruction execution.  (Jester's answer below is really clever).   The first question is generally "no", CLI exists to handle interrupt disable and protected mode is used to prevent applications from doing bad things like hogging the CPU by disabling interrupts.  The "one instruction" duration is much more interesting:  why would you want to do that? ("because of my assignment" is a really pointless answer).  What would you *usefully* do with it?

Comment: @FUZxxl: Oops, sorry, OP asked the 2 questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, loading `SS` with a `MOV` will inhibit external interrupts for the next instruction. This is what the instruction set reference says:

> Loading the SS register with a MOV instruction inhibits all interrupts
>   until after the execution of the next instruction. This operation
>   allows a stack pointer to be loaded into the ESP register with the
>   next instruction (MOV ESP, stack-pointer value) before an interrupt
>   occurs.

Comment: Loading `SS` with a `POP` will also inhibit external interrupts for the next instruction.

Comment: For those thinking about the same exploit that I was, the manual says: "If a sequence of consecutive instructions each loads the SS register (using MOV or POP), only the first is
guaranteed to inhibit or suppress events in this way."

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet does the trick:

```
pushf
pop  ax
and  ax, FDFFh
push ax
popf               ;This disables interrupts, You didn't use "CLI"
; Here IF is clear
sti
```

Comment: The IF flag controls hardware interrupts. Issuing a syscall over the `int 0x80` on Linux is still possible.

Comment: @cad You're correct. The OP's question is all about hardware interrupts. The OP forgot to remove the word *software* from the title. See the EditHistory.