# Why we need to disable all interrupts at system startup or system initialization?

Tags: assembly, kernel, startup, interrupt

What is need for disabling all interrupts at system initialization or at startup code level . If I do not disable the interrupts what will happen??

Comment: You have to because your interrupt handlers are not yet installed. If you don;t disable them and you get an interrupt, the system/startup will crash.

Comment: you don't want the interrupts to fire before you have the corresponding handlers installed, and all datastructures initialized which the handlers uses. else you might not get unpredictable behavior.

Comment: If you are writing a real mode OS then disabling interrupts may not be required. The default real mode interrupt table will be in place for the BIOS/hardware in question. If you intend to create a protected mode OS, you'll need to disable interrupts before you switch into protected mode. If you switch into protected mode with interrupts on and there is no Interrupt Vector Table (IVT) it will likely triple fault. Once in protected mode, you can set up an IVT, and then re-enable interrupts.

Answer (score 7):

There are certain situations interrupts are unwanted, so they are disabled.
The examples are numerous but off the top of my head I can come up with these:

- **Modification of**  `ss:(e)sp`**.** If an interrupt is fired, the `flags` register is pushed onto the stack. An invalid stack value will move that copy to some random location. Alterating `ss:(e)sp` is not atomic, at least on x86, because it consists of multiple instructions, so an interrupt can fire in between.
  However, if you write your code properly, you can achieve the same atomicity without disabling interrupts here because they are [automatically disabled on certain occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330911/how-to-disable-interrupts-for-one-instruction).

  @MichaelPetch uttered some specialty about 8088 processors (the "weaker brother" of the 8086, the first x86 processor), depicting an exception to these "certain occasions," in the comments to this answer:

  > That is true about interrupts being turned off until the end of the
  >   next instruction (after moving a value into `SS` ), but there were 8088
  >   processors with a bug where the interrupts weren't properly turned off
  >   after a `SS` change. Those of us (the dinosaurs) will often put `CLI`/`STI`
  >   around the `SS:SP` update just in case (Chances of running an 8088
  >   system with such a bug is likely near zero). From a historical
  >   perspective, this [PC mag article](https://books.google.com/books?id=1L7PVOhfUIoC&lpg=PA492&ots=zjAKTcSu3k&pg=PA492#v=onepage&q&f=false) may shed some light on this ancient
  >   issue.

  <sub>(Code formatters added.)</sub>
- **Lack of an IDT/IVT.** While the Protected Mode IDT is initialized or the 16-bit Real Mode IVT is modified (or zeroed out or something), an interrupt would jump to some memory location no instruction is located at.

In general, you can say that operations modifying the IDT/IVT in some non-atomic manner need to disable interrupts.

---

As an aside: I myself have written several bootloaders already and usually disable interrupts throughout the whole runtime of the bootloader. In Protected Mode, I reenable them eventually. Linux 4.2 handles it similarly. If you're interested, read its source code (`/arch/x86/boot/`) or that from Minix!

Comment: Actually on x86 there is no need to disable interrupts in the first case due to a special rule: Interrupts are disabled for one cycle after a `pop %ss` so you have time to set the stack pointer.

Comment: @FUZxxl Done. Could ya take a look at it, please?

Comment: That's about right but be careful, there is subtle behaviour associated when you execute multiple such instructions in a row.

Comment: @FUZxxl That is true about interrupts being turned off until the end of the next instruction (after moving a value into _SS_ ), but there were 8088 processors with a bug where the interrupts weren't properly turned off after a _SS_ change. Those of us (the dinosaurs) will often put CLI/STI around the _SS:SP_ update just in case (Chances of running an 8088 system with such a bug is likely near zero). From a historical perspective, this [PC mag article](https://books.google.com/books?id=1L7PVOhfUIoC&lpg=PA492&ots=zjAKTcSu3k&pg=PA492#v=onepage&q&f=false) may shed some light on this ancient issue.